# Traveling with sex toys to Kuwait

Tags: customs-and-immigration, sex

I will be traveling to Kuwait and am intending on taking my 2 favourite sex toys with me. Will the x-ray detect my sex toys in my checked in luggage and if they do what will happen?

Comment: There are restrictions on electrical and electronic items in checked baggage, particularly those with larger lithium or lithium-ion batteries: you probably won't be affected but check with the airline to be sure.